# How can I write an XSLT which preserves namespace references in text elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I'm writing an XSLT which will convert SOAP 1.2 faults to SOAP 1.1 faults. I'm using XSLT v2.0, and I'm doing the transformation in Java; probably using Xerces or whatever XML-transformation Java comes bundled with. Soap 1.2 faults have pieces that look like this:

```
<soap12:code xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Value>soap12:Sender</soap12:Value>
  ...
</soap12:code>
```

But Soap 1.1 faults look like this:

```
<soap11:Fault xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <faultcode>soap11:Server</faultcode>
  ...
</soap11:Fault>
```

So, the tricky part is that my XSLT needs to generate something like "soap11:server". It needs to refer to the soap11 namespace with whatever appropriate prefix the XSLT engine has chosen. It might be a prefix like "soap11", but it might also be a prefix like "soap" or "ns1", depending on what the input document looked like. Now for attributes and elements, the XSLT engine handles this for you, generating attributes/elements with the correct prefixes. However, it doesn't modify these namespace references when they occur in raw text. Here is the relevant piece of my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    exclude-result-prefixes="soap12"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="soap12:Fault">
        <soap11:Fault>
            <!-- presumably some mapping logic will go here -->
            <faultcode>soap11:Server</faultcode>
            ...
        </soap11:Fault>
    </xsl:template>
    ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a way to tell XSLT that "soap11:Server" is, in this context, referring to the soap11 namespace?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It needs to refer to the soap11 namespace with whatever appropriate prefix the XSLT engine has chosen." ? You as a stylesheet author decide what prefixes to use.

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying I can rely on the fact that, given the XSLT i've described above; the output will 100% always use a SOAP 1.1 namespace prefix of "soap11"? I was unaware that was a part of the XSLT specification. I thought the XSLT engine was free to choose its own namespace prefixes.

Comment: You are introducing the soap11 namespace to the output document, right? It's not present in the input document. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes you're right. I think you're right - it's a safe assumption that the XML will be generated using "soap11" as the correct prefix, so it is safe to "hard code" the prefix in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code is correct**. You can verify this by running the transformation and:

1. Looking at the result.
2. Parsing the result with an XML parser to verify this is a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I assumed that I needed to take special consideration to inform the XSLT parser that "soap11:Server" was referring to a namespace prefix; however, this is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to sort out whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0. You say you're using XSLT 2.0, but you also say that you are using the default XSLT engine in the JDK, which only supports XSLT 1.0.

The question is relevant because XSLT 1.0 allows the transformation engine (in fact, the serializer) to choose what prefixes will be used in the output, whereas XSLT 2.0 is prescriptive about the choice of prefixes (except in the rare cases where the processor has to dream up a prefix from nowhere).

So the answer is: if you're using an XSLT 1.0 engine, as appears to be the case, then the language spec gives you no guarantees about namespace prefixes in the output, though in practice most processors will do the reasonable thing in straightforward cases. If you want a guarantee, you have to move to an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Sorry about omitting that detail. I'm currently using Xalan, which you're right, is an XSLT 1.0 processor. I said I was using XSLT 2.0 based on my XSLT's "version" tag but that was misleading.

Comment: Small addition: XSLT 2.0 also provide QName data type handling.